# How to get the exact time from a server by domain name only?

Tags: python, date, time, server, jupyter-notebook

I know python and jupyter a little bit so cut me some slack. I want to know if there is way to get the time of server through just the domain name. Like for example you have a domain such as blah.blahblah.com and you want to get what is the time to seconds on that server/domain.

More explanation:
My case is that a website releases some available stocks on a specific date and time each week; because there are thousands of applicants and claimants, its very important to refresh your webpage on exact time of that page and click as fast as you can to get the results and apply for one otherwise its gone (in less than a second usually). So, I want to get the time of that API to refresh my page precisely on the time to see the results and get one. I can't use a bot as its illegal and the server rejects that.

I'd appreciate if u help,

thanks

Comment: Generally speaking, no - some would even consider this in certain setups/environments to be a security risk (information disclosure, to be precise). Can you elaborate a bit on what exactly you plan to do with this information? What does it matter to you what time a clock on some arbitrary server on the Internet is set to? It may help us figure out if you may be encountering an XY problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your use case, it may be valid for you to use a geolocation API to first get the (estimated) geographic location of the server (through its IP address). From the result, you can determine the time zone and therefore the local time of the server. I'm not a regular user of such APIs, so I cannot recommend any, but by searching on the Internet, you will find plenty (look for geolocation, IP address). Similarly, you will find APIs that get you the timezone for a given country/city pair.

Edit: It's obvious that this answer doesn't address your refined question.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the OP’s question. It doesn’t matter where a server is physically located; the clock can be set to whatever time the operator desires.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know what city and country the server is located. But the point is, I want to get the exact seconds of that server. Like for example, there might be two APIs in a city and they differ on the seconds (the technician might have had set the time manually rather than set it to time zone automatically). Is this possible ? please let me know if you need more explanations. This thing is crucial for me.

Comment: It might be possible to find out about the exact clock settings of the server through some indirect means. For example, if the server publishes some web site which includes a current timestamp (i.e. when the web page was created). Due to network latency variations, server load and other factors, the result may not be accurate enough for your use case. As you mentioned in your updated answer that the web site regularly publishes offerings, you might be able to determine the server clock setting through observing these events a few times.

Comment: Thank you Izydrmr for your answer. The only problem with this website is that if at that specific hour, offerings are published, you (user) should in fact refresh the page to get the results, otherwise you won't notice that. So, I want to know when to refresh it to get the offerings. (you know by calculate the network latency, ping, refresh rate, etc.)